# How to prevent Matplotlib from changing time series data on x-axis to 1970s?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, matplotlib, seaborn

I am trying to plot data from pandas data frame with python using Seaborn (and Matplotlib). I have the dates set as the index values in the dataframe starting at 2016-02-03 and ending at the current date. The values are of type datetime (not strings). No matter what I try, when I plot a graph of the data I have, it is changing the dates and going all the way back to 1970 instead of the dates that I have. Would appreciate any help.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import requests
import os
import pandas as pd
import json
from datetime import *
from percent import change
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show, output_file
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.models.tools import HoverTool
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns 
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
from matplotlib.dates import DateFormatter

#constants
daily = "TIME_SERIES_DAILY"
symbols = ["COIN"]

COLOR = sns.color_palette('Set2')[4]

currentdate = date.today()


lastweek = currentdate  - timedelta(days=7)
lastyear = currentdate - timedelta(days=364)
lastyear = str(lastyear)
currentdate = str(currentdate)


api_key = REDACTED
base_url = 'https://www.alphavantage.co/query?'

params = {'function': daily,
         'outputsize': 'full',
         'symbol': symbols[0],
         'horizon': '3month',
         'datatype': 'csv',
         'apikey': api_key}


response = requests.get(base_url, params = params) #.json is same as json.loads()
#response_dict = response.json()
with open('eurusd.csv', 'wb') as file:
    file.write(response.content)

sns.set(style="ticks", context="talk")
plt.style.use("dark_background")



df = pd.read_csv("eurusd.csv", parse_dates = True)
df.set_index('timestamp', inplace = True)
df = df.iloc[::-1] #flips

plt.rc('axes', titlesize=18)     # fontsize of the axes title
plt.rc('axes', labelsize=14)    # fontsize of the x and y labels
plt.rc('xtick', labelsize=13)    # fontsize of the tick labels
plt.rc('ytick', labelsize=13)    # fontsize of the tick labels
#plt.rc('legend', fontsize=13)    # legend fontsize
plt.rc('font', size=10)          # controls default text sizes

plt.figure(figsize=(8,5), tight_layout=True)

a = sns.lineplot(data = df['close'], color=sns.color_palette('Set2')[4],linewidth = 2)

#graph extras
sns.despine()
plt.xticks(rotation = 45, ha = 'right')
plt.xticks([500,1000]) # to replace with specific name: plt.xticks([500,1000], [name1, name2 etc])
a.spines['left'].set_color(COLOR)      
a.spines['bottom'].set_color(COLOR)
a.xaxis.label.set_color(COLOR)       
a.yaxis.label.set_color(COLOR)       
a.tick_params(axis='x', colors= COLOR)   
a.tick_params(axis='y', colors=COLOR)
a.set(xlabel=None)
a.set(ylabel=None)
a.set_title('Stock Chart', color = COLOR)

for tick_label in a.axes.get_yticklabels():
    tick_label.set_color(sns.color_palette('Set2')[4])
for tick_label in a.axes.get_xticklabels():
    tick_label.set_color(sns.color_palette('Set2')[4])

a.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%Y-%m'))
plt.show()
```

image of the plot
[image]

First few lines of CSV data:

```
2016-02-03  18.00  18.88  16.0000  18.20  4157947
2016-02-04  18.26  19.42  17.5725  18.50   469941
2016-02-05  18.84  18.88  17.5200  17.60   220160
2016-02-08  17.52  18.00  15.7200  15.85   372112
2016-02-09  15.50  15.50  12.7482  12.81   744115
```

[image: example of the csv data]

Comment: It might help to clarify things if you'd [add](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71427472/edit) the first few lines of `"eurusd.csv"` as text.

Comment: Are you using recent matplotlib, pandas and seaborn versions?

Comment: According to [How to implement Lineplot using seaborn with x-axis as "Date"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56819030/how-to-implement-lineplot-using-seaborn-with-x-axis-as-date) having the timestamp as a column should work: `sns.lineplot(data=df, x='timestamp', y='Close')`.  But your `sns.lineplot(data=df['close'])` should work as well, at least with the current versions of the libraries.

Comment: The versions weren't updated, but I just did and it's still not showing correctly. Changing the syntax for displaying the axes also doesn't work. I suspect that the best bet will be working around by parsing through the dates and then letting that code overwrite what the axes say (rather than using the built in functionality).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running your example with the latest versions seems to use correct dates for the x-axis:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

df_str = '''timestamp open close high low volume
2016-02-03  18.00  18.88  16.0000  18.20  4157947
2016-02-04  18.26  19.42  17.5725  18.50   469941
2016-02-05  18.84  18.88  17.5200  17.60   220160
2016-02-08  17.52  18.00  15.7200  15.85   372112
2016-02-09  15.50  15.50  12.7482  12.81   744115'''
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(df_str), delim_whitespace=True)
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(ncols=2, figsize=(12, 5))
sns.lineplot(data=df, x='timestamp', y='close', ax=ax1)
sns.lineplot(data=df.set_index('timestamp')['close'], ax=ax2)
```

[image: seaborn sns.lineplot with dates as x-axis]

With a longer list of dates, only the year, or year-month are shown:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'timestamp': pd.date_range('2016-02-03', '2022-02-03')})
df['close'] = np.random.normal(0.02, 1, len(df)).cumsum() + 20
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(ncols=2, figsize=(15, 5))
sns.lineplot(data=df, x='timestamp', y='close', ax=ax1)
sns.lineplot(data=df.iloc[:len(df) // 2], x='timestamp', y='close', ax=ax2)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: sns.lineplot with 6 years x axis]