# Overlapping xlabels for Seaborn Lineplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, jupyter-lab

I've come across the issue of having overlapping `xlables` on a Seaborn line plot. The data set has multiple occurrences of those labels, which is understandable. But is there a way to fix the `xlabels` without having to change the format of the plot or the data frame?

The `xlabels` have been formatted to the `Timestamp` type earlier on, and the plot is shown below;

[image: Seaborn Line Plot]

code:

```py
plt.figure(figsize=(15,10))
sns.lineplot(data=data_no_orkney, x="Data_Month_Date", y=percentage)
plt.xticks(list(set(data_no_orkney.Data_Month_Date)))
#plt.axvline(x=pd.Timestamp(year=2020,month=3,day=23), color='r', ls='--', label="Date of first lockdown")
plt.xlabel("Year")
plt.ylabel("Percentage meeting target")
plt.show()
```

Also, would it be correct of me to assume that the solid, blue line in the middle is the mean out of the values shown in the lighter blue area? I've never seen such line plot before, but that's more or less my understanding, judging by the looks of it.

I tried using `plt.xticks(list)`, where I tried having the list to contain unduplicated `Timestamp` (date) values. The only result was that it to took the code longer to run, and  the labels did not change.

Comment: To understand a seaborn lineplot, it might help to read the [docs](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.lineplot.html).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/50033189/6361531

Comment: The easiest approach would be to have (leave?) the timestamps in pandas datetime format. (Matplotlib will take care for proper formatting, or you can assign a specific [date formatter](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/dates_api.html).)  See e.g. [How to implement Lineplot using seaborn with x-axis as "Date"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56819030/how-to-implement-lineplot-using-seaborn-with-x-axis-as-date)